# Dynamic, multidimensional, rectangular, numeric arrays in C++ (as in NumPy or Matlab)

Tags: c++, arrays, numpy

In Matlab or NumPy it's very easy to create numerical arrays which are rectangular, multidimensional and dynamic. Those classes also have nice indexing functionality. Furthermore, they have data stored in one linear buffer.

I'm looking for something similiar in C++, syntax could be for example:

```
DoubleArray arr(size_x, size_y);
arr[x][y] = 5;
double * ptr = arr.getRawData() // returns the underlying linear storage
```

I think C++ does not offer anything built-in to do so. The only library I know is Eigen, but it has the drawback that matrices/arrays are always 2-dimensional.

Is there a good and easy way to achieve what I want? Most important is that I do not have to mess around manually with indexing, and that data is stored in one buffer (vs. vector of vectors).

Comment: Does this work for you? http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Absolutely NO, because it won't result in a consecutive buffer. Did you even read the question?

Comment: @DonghuiZhang: Eigen is an option, but it does not support n-dimensional matrices/arrays unfortunately.

Comment: @Michael Well, you could wrap a one dimensional `std::vector<double>` into your own matrix class, that does the indexing logic. Though implementing an indexing operator like `[x][y]` would require some extra efforts. You're probably better off with an overwritten `double operator(int,int)` then.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What you're saying is correct. But - I'm for sure not the only one who needs such a multi dimensional array which any Matlab or NumPy user uses daily. So I really really wonder whether there's a widespread standard solution for that task in C++. (Eigen is an option, though.)

Comment: @Michael _"Eigen is an option, though"_ That would have been my next recommendation :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Eigen does not support n-dimensional matrices natively, and I'd wish for something even more basic - basically just indexing into a buffer containing n-dimensional data.

Comment: @Michael Write that wrapper class I've mentioned then, its probably easier than searching for an appropriate 3rd party resource that meets all of your requirements.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html?

Comment: Matlab and numpy are high-level environments where the focus is on ease for the programmer. C++ is a low level language where the focus is on efficiency. So you should implement your own C++ classes to hold the subset of possible matrices and arrays you are interested in, and do that efficiently.

Comment: Looks to me that boost multi_array that @Jens recommended should satisfy your need. @Michael?

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: I disagree on that. C++'s STL offers a tremendous amount of higher level concepts to the application programmer so that he/she can think on a higher abstraction level, while the library cares about efficient implementation. So why not add an n-dimensional array library?

Comment: @DonghuiZhang: Yes that seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that C++ does not offer a built-in multidim array, because it is rather easy to write one but how it should be implemented depends on your requirements. I was curious on how one could get such a multidimensional array and came up with this:

```
template <int DIMS> 
struct multidimarray {
    typedef int value_type;
    value_type* data;
    int* dimensions;
    multidimarray(int* dims,value_type* d) : dimensions(dims),data(d) {}
    multidimarray<DIMS-1> operator[](int index){
        int s = 1;
        for (int i=1;i<DIMS;i++){ s *= dimensions[i];}
        return multidimarray<DIMS-1>(dimensions+1,data+s*index);
    }
};
template <> struct multidimarray<1> {
    typedef int value_type;
    value_type* data;
    int* dimensions;
    multidimarray(int* dims,value_type* d) : dimensions(dims),data(d) {}
    value_type operator[](int index){ return *(data+index); }    
};
```

It is not the most efficient implementation, at least the size of the subarrays should not be computed for each access. Also it would be more convenient to use, if a wrapper was added that handles creation and deletion of the `data`. However, it seems to work (no guarantee, not more tested than with the following code):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int imax = 4;
    int jmax = 4;
    int kmax = 3;
    std::vector<int> d;
    d.push_back(imax); d.push_back(jmax);d.push_back(kmax);
    std::vector<int> data;
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){data.push_back(i);}
    multidimarray<3> md = multidimarray<3>(&d[0],&data[0]);   
    for (int i=0;i<imax;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<jmax;j++){
            for (int k=0;k<kmax;k++){
                std::cout << md[i][j][k] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Sorry for the lack of `auto` and brace initialization, but this is pre-C++11.

Oh well, and I just realized that the `multidimarray<1>::operator[]` should of course return a reference instead of a value.

As I mentioned above, requirements may wildly differ for your specific application. Nevertheless, I hope this helps ;)

Comment: You need to mess about to get aray[i], array[i][j] and array[i][j][k] all working for one type that holds the number of dimensions dynamically. it is possible however.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean not completely sure what you mean

Comment: We can build an "array class" with the ability to add or remove dimensions dynamically at runtime, and multi-dimensional array access using overloaded [] operators. However it's not entirely straightforwards.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean that would involve intensive copying of the underlying data, if I understand correctly what you want to do. I think I could live without this feature. Adding a dimension "at the front" (eg. from [2][4] to [3][2][4]) I think would be trivial and changing the dimensionality (eg. from [2][3][4] to [2][12]) is already possible with my approach. [PS: I am not trying to defend my code by all means, just happy to get some feedback]